X-Ray mod is disabled, Not Flipped faces and Object is still transparent?
I am making a map for my game and decided to make it in Blender and then export to Unity, while I made models indivually and imported them into one big project so I can build the map, I don't have issue on any other of the models but in this particular model, even though x-ray is closed and I checked the flipped normals one by one. Nothing seems to changed. How can I fix this?





Seems like the material simply has some transparency. Would it be asked too much if you also included a screenshot of your material setup?
